# Wireguard - no handshake

Tags: server, vpn

I've had a Wireguard server up for like 2yrs now (Server is currently running Ubuntu 21.04). Works great on a few devices I have.
As of recent, I thought I'd add a new client or two to the VPN. I recently put up an Ubuntu server 20.04.3. So, I install Wireguard, create the keys, create the config wg0...swapping the publickeys, bring the server back up bring the client up and... Bubkis. No handshake.

I can't figure out what is stopping the handshake. Does anybody know if there are any issues with Wireguard in 20.04, 21.04? I get nothing on dkms status, but i figuring that because it's already in the kernel. I'm not sure how to trouble shoot this anymore.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: [21.04 is EOL](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19913/end-of-life-notice-ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-reached-end-of-life-on-january?cb=1). I suggest using 21.10 if you prefer faster releases, or 20.04 LTS for stability.

Comment: Please double, triple, quadruple... check your IP addresses, network masks, port numbers, and keys in your configuration files. Is there a UDP connectivity between your client and server for the UDP port you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Good to know about the "End of life". Wonder why Raspberry pi still offers the OS for download?

Comment: I have to manage that closely as I'm running Nextcloud and I can't go above php 8.0. What would you guys suggest? That aside, I saw some generic posts elsewhere that the Ubuntu Pi OS had issues with Wireguard. My topology requires this server and an upcoming server be on a VPN so I can do totally remote data backup. Any suggestions at this point are appreciated.

Comment: FedKad - I must have checked everything about 80 times now. Ha

Comment: As a side note, the server that's at EoL is actually the server that's working. It's the VPN server and I have a number of devices already on it. With my anticipated topology I just wanted to add two more.

Comment: I do often times find MTU issues with wireguard. Therefor i began to add an MTU line to every wireguard config to reduce the MTU to 1200. 
MTU issues often shwo up by established connections that suddenly dont work properly anymore. For example, ssh does not work properly or Kodi/plex refuses to stream videos. Often times there is no error message.
Apart from that: What do you mean by handshake? As far as i know there is no handshake in wireguard to establish a vpn connection, but I might be wrong. In other words, it does connect on purpes or when KeepAlive is set.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the issue is or was. I spent about a month trying to figure it out to no avail. Luckily I did have a machine that was working correctly. Rather than spend more time looking for the needle I decided to clone the machine that was working and regenerated keys. Now everything works.
I'm a knucklehead, but I was working with someone that really knew his shit...and even he was stumped. Everything was set up correctly. I could NC to both machines. and it worked if I used an internal network address...but as soon as I put in the public IP bubkus. It was just weird.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying an MTU value in the interface section of the Wireguard configuration file. e.g.

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.7.0.1/24, fddd:2c4:2c4:2c4::1/64
PrivateKey = <private_key_here>
ListenPort = 51820
# https://gist.github.com/diyism/1b80903a83776675031c73ae499438d8
MTU = 1300
```