# Wireguard failure and unattended-upgrades: plausible explanation?

Tags: server, upgrade, vpn, wireguard

A Linode hosted Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server acts as a Wireguard VPN.

```
$ uname -r
6.0.10-x86_64-ABCNNN
```

Installation using https://github.com/angristan/wireguard-install is painless and works perfectly with Windows 10, iPhone, and iPad clients.

Except, of course, when it does not. Over the last 6 months or so the server has stopped working a number of times, producing errors on all clients:

```
2023-03-14 23:36:58.002: [TUN] [i7] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (n.n.n.n:51820)
2023-03-14 23:37:03.074: [TUN] [i7] Handshake for peer 1 (n.n.n.n:51820) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
2023-03-14 23:37:03.074: [TUN] [i7] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (n.n.n.n:51820)
...
```

After removal and re-installation, using `wireguard-install`, the VPN server once again works, though with consequent reconfiguration of all clients

The remarkable thing about this is that the machine has not been manually updated nor modified in any way.

It may have been modified by the `unattended-upgrades` service, but there is nothing in the logs to show. Is this a plausible explanation for the VPN breakage?

As an experiment, the `unattended-upgrades` service has been disabled. Which may or may not be a good idea but seems to be the only way to test the hypothesis. Does the panel have any other thoughts?

Possibly related: [Wireguard - no handshake](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392719/wireguard-no-handshake)

Comment: Looks like you're running an unsupported kernel there. 6.0.10

Comment: @popey. Unsupported by whom? Canonical? I suspect it was rebuilt by the wireguard-install script.

Comment: Not just Canonical. We generally only support the kernels which ship with Ubuntu or are available in the repo. Not random ones built by users or random scripts.